# need one record in duplicate records

Tags: sql, hana-studio

Here is the table:

Activity table

```
|Place of order|Order NR  | Nr of activity|type of activity| Date of activity|
|01            |1         | 00001         |      1         | Date1           |
|01            |1         | 00002         |      1         | Date1           |
|01            |1         | 00003         |      2         | Date2           |
|02            |1         | 00001         |      1         | Date9           |
|01            |2         | 00001         |      1         | Date4           |
|01            |2         | 00003         |      2         | Date5           |
|01            |2         | 00002         |      3         | Date3           |
|02            |2         | 00001         |      1         | Date10          |
|02            |2         | 00006         |      2         | Date11          |
|02            |2         | 00018         |      2         | Date11          |
|02            |1         | 00002         |      2         | Date1           |
```

Place of order and order number have to be together for uniqueness,
`Activity Type 1 is order placed;` and
`Activity Type 2 is order dispatched`
there are other activites that are not interesting in this context.

There was an error (don't know how it happened). For a few orders (Place of order and Order Nr.), the same order has been placed and discharged twice on the same day, but it has a different activity nr.

I am trying to get dates of activity type 1 and type 2 for each order along with the place of order and order Nr.

**Results should look like:**

For Orders Placed:

```
|Place of order|Order NR  | Nr of activity|type of activity| Date of activity|
|01            |1         | 00001         |      1         | Date1           |
|02            |1         | 00001         |      1         | Date9           |
|01            |2         | 00001         |      1         | Date4           |
|02            |2         | 00001         |      1         | Date10          |
```

For Orders discharge:

```
|Place of order|Order NR  | Nr of activity|type of activity| Date of activity|
|01            |1         | 00003         |      2         | Date2           |
|02            |1         | 00002         |      2         | Date12          |
|01            |2         | 00002         |      2         | Date5           |
|02            |2         | 00006         |      2         | Date11          |
```

I can't figure out how to exclude the duplicates from the results. That means I need only one row (the row with minimum activity number).

Comment: MySQL or sql-server?

Comment: I don't know the difference, I need SQL statements :)

Comment: Once you know if you're working with MySQL or SQL Server, then tag the correct product

Comment: Run `select @@version` if the result is just a number it's MySQL otherwise it will show you the version of "Microsoft SQL Server" you are using.

Comment: SQL scripts are written SAP HANA studio!

Comment: I guess "Place of order and order number have to be together for uniqueness" means those colums identify an order? I guess you mean that an order should be placed only once and discharged only once (on at least that date)? I guess the an order's correct placing & discharging are the ones with the smallest activity number? (You are not clear.) (You show the table & say that it shouldn't have a certain property but you don't make clear just what the table should look like.) Please don't write in fragments.

Comment: Dear Philipxy, All your guesses are correct, I gave the Table, explained the table. and I gave the tables how i want them to be and I mentioned where i have the problem. I will consider your suggestion and make my next posts very clear. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this :

```
  ;with cte as(
    select rank() over(order by [Nr of activity] ) as rid , * from TableName
    ) select * from cte where rid=1
```

Comment: @Anotny wait, its giving something, let me check!

Comment: hey, it did seems working **without `;`**, but a small problem. The records with activity type 2 which were double are `n` in number. My investigation shows there are only twice marked as dischrged. That being said the table should have `2*n` of double records before filtering and `n` records after filtering. I get `n-150` records. Any suggestions or comments?

Comment: Another issue is I cannot join or combine this statement to another statement with Where IN for example!

Comment: O o.. the RID changes very drastically if the Activity Nr changes! it takes Number of the row when the Nr of Activity changes as rid.

Comment: @sai We can join to the multi statements in CTE

Comment: @RID changes to a certain number where the type changes. I didnt get the logic though!

Comment: Yes correct , If RID=1 its distinct data and Rid >1 means its duplicate